# How to identify which lambda fails in AWS and rerun it

Tags: java, aws-lambda

Once a file is uploading to S3,it triggers aws lambda to do some processing, how can I identify which lambda fails and rerun that lambda using Java. The failing can be caused by error, out of memory, time out, exception and so on.

Comment: Please share some code and error logs

Comment: I think you'd have to use CloudWatch Logs to identify which functions failed. Of course, depending upon the failure, you could handle it better. What type of failures are you experiencing?

Comment: Yes, the error messages are captured by CloudWatch logs, but is there any way to extract that message? Using another lambda? The failure like time-out, out of memory and exception. So what I want to do is that, identify failed lambda and rerun that lambda.

Comment: @Qian you can implement that functionality inside of the first lamda' code. Like if (res !== 200) invoke lambda again. And you can add a tries checker.